# switch radiobox to checkbox to EditText using enum

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am creating a quiz with different question types. To call these types I would like to use Enum then a switch statement in my activity to make a specific type visible.

Here is what I have in my Question class

```
public class Question {
    private String question;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private int answerNumber;
    private enum type {RADIO, CHECKBOX, TEXTENTRY}; 

    public Question(){}

    public Question(String question, String option1, String option2, String option3, int answerNumber, int type) {
        this.question = question;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.option3 = option3;
        this.answerNumber = answerNumber;
        this.type = type; // expression expected, not sure how to approach this
    }
}
```

I manually created my getters + setters as I receive this message if I try to generate them with Android Studio

'no fields without getter + setter where found'

```
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```

This is what I have in my DBHelper.

```
    private void fillQuestionsTable() {
        Question q1 = new Question("1 is correct", "a", "b","c",1,0);
        addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("2 is correct", "a", "b","c",2,1);
        addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3 = new Question("3 is correct", "a", "b","c",3,2);
        addQuestion(q3);
    }

    private void addQuestion(Question question){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1, question.getOption1());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2, question.getOption2());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3, question.getOption3());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWERNUMBER, question.getAnswerNumber());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE, question.getType());
        db.insert(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
    }

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions(){
        List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList <>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Question question = new Question();
                question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
                question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
                question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
                question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
                question.setAnswerNumber(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWERNUMBER)));
                question.setType(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE)));
                questionList.add(question);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
        return questionList;
    }
```

And in my activity this is what I am using to try and switch the question types 
-All views set to INVISIBLE to start then methods to make them VISIBLE-

```
private void showNextQuestion(){
    if (questionCounter < getQuestionCounter){
            currentQuestion = questionList.get(questionCounter);

            question.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
            rb1.setText(currentQuestion.getOption1());
            rb2.setText(currentQuestion.getOption2());
            rb3.setText(currentQuestion.getOption3());

            //switch question formats

            int type = (int)

            question.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion()).questionList.get.questionType;
            switch (questionType) {
                // seems to like questionList better in here... still not sure how to bring up the enums
                case Question.RADIO:
                    showRadioGroup();
                    break;
                case Question.CHECKBOX:
                    showCheckboxes();
                    break;
                case Question.TEXTENTRY:
                    showTypeAnswer();
                    break;
            }
            questionCounter++;
```

The idea is to bring everything from my Array - yes? -a bit confused here-
if I use questionList  which is my array can't resolve 
if I use getAllQuestions in case can't resolve getAllQuestions
if I use typeAnswer or questionList in case can't resolve RADIO nor TEXTENTRY
Sorry I was trying different approaches.

Also just realized I will have a hard time trying to verify a text entry with the code as is. Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking when you say `private enum type {RADIO, CHECKBOX, TEXTENTRY};` you can (need to) then use **type** like as if it were a class.

So you need an additional line to declare an object of **type** for it to be a memeber ( `enum ??? {...}` is implicitly static and final (if my limited understanding is correct)) e.g. :-

```
private mytype = type;
```

Here's some code that may help you understand how to construct (in a few ways), get and set using enums :-

```
public class Question {

    public enum qtype {RADIO,CHECKBOX,TEXTENTRY} //<<< accessible outside perhaps prefereable

    private enum altqtype {RADIO, CHECKBOX, TEXTENTRY} //<<<< Alternative if you want private (restrictive)

    private String question;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private int answerNumber;
    private long Id;

    // Define members of the enum's
    private qtype mytype;
    private altqtype alternative_qtype;
    private qtype another;

    public Question(){}

    public Question(
            String question,
            String option1,
            String option2,
            String option3,
            int answerNumber,
            int type,         //<<<< pass as an int
            String stype,     //<<<< pass as a String
            long id, //<<<< likely needed
            qtype questiontype //<<<< pass as an qtype (e.g. qtype.RADIO)

    ) {
        this.question = question;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.option3 = option3;
        this.answerNumber = answerNumber;
        this.Id = id;    //<<<< You may well need this to reference DB from Arraylist

        // Setting enum's
        this.mytype = questiontype; // set to passed value

        this.alternative_qtype = altqtype.CHECKBOX; // Sets to default
        // Set it accoring to the string passed
        if (isValidTypeString(stype)) {
            this.alternative_qtype = altqtype.valueOf(stype);
        }

        this.another = convertIntToQtype(type);
    }

    public qtype getMytype() {
        return mytype;
    }

    public void setMytype(qtype mytype) {
        this.mytype = mytype;
    }

    //Given an int convert it to a qtype
    private qtype convertIntToQtype(int type){
        qtype rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY;
        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                rv = qtype.RADIO;
                break;
            case 2:
                rv = qtype.CHECKBOX;
                break;
            case 4:
                rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY;
                break;
            default:
                rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY;
        }
        return rv;
    }

    // Check if a given string is valid as a question type
    // Note done for alternative
    private boolean isValidTypeString(String pv) {
        boolean rv = false;
        altqtype[] typearray = altqtype.values();
        for (altqtype aqt: typearray) {
            if (pv.equals(aqt.toString())) {
                rv = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

---

### Working Example

here's a working example that :-

- utilises enum's
- utilises both ArrayList and Cursor

  - ArrayList used for asking question and for List of questions (2nd)
  - Cursor used for List of questions (1st List)
- traverses questions via PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons
- Allows answer (no answer checking) to be one of Edit text, Radio Button or Checkbox according to to the question, displaying the appropriate View.

#### Question.java

```
public class Question {

    public enum qtype {RADIO,CHECKBOX,TEXTENTRY} //<<< accessible outside perhaps prefereable

    private enum altqtype {RADIO, CHECKBOX, TEXTENTRY} //<<<< Alternative if you want private (restrictive)

    private String question;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private int answerNumber;
    private long rowid;

    // Define members of the enum's
    private qtype mytype;
    private altqtype alternative_qtype;
    private qtype another;

    public Question(){}

    public Question(
            String question, String option1, String option2, String option3,
            int answerNumber, qtype type, long id) {
        this.question = question;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.option3 = option3;
        this.answerNumber = answerNumber;
        this.mytype = type;
        this.rowid = id;
    }

    public Question(
            String question, String option1, String option2, String option3,
            int answerNumber, qtype type
    ){
        this(question,option1,option2,option3,answerNumber,type,-1);
    }

    //<<<< Note constrcutor for demonstration of enums
    public Question(
            String question,
            String option1,
            String option2,
            String option3,
            int answerNumber,
            int type,         //<<<< pass as an int
            String stype,     //<<<< pass as a String
            long id, //<<<< likely needed
            qtype questiontype //<<<< pass as an qtype (e.g. qtype.RADIO)

    ) {
        this.question = question;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.option3 = option3;
        this.answerNumber = answerNumber;
        this.rowid = id;    //<<<< You may well need this to reference DB from Arraylist

        // Setting enum's
        this.mytype = questiontype; // set to passed value

        this.alternative_qtype = altqtype.CHECKBOX; // Sets to default
        // Set it accoring to the string passed
        if (isValidTypeString(stype)) {
            this.alternative_qtype = altqtype.valueOf(stype);
        }

        this.another = convertIntToQtype(type);
    }

    public qtype getMytype() {
        return mytype;
    }

    public void setMytype(qtype mytype) {
        this.mytype = mytype;
    }

    //Given an int convert it to a qtype
    private qtype convertIntToQtype(int type){
        qtype rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY;
        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                rv = qtype.RADIO;
                break;
            case 2:
                rv = qtype.CHECKBOX;
                break;
            case 4:
                rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY;
                break;
            default:
                rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY;
        }
        return rv;
    }

    // Check if a given string is valid as a question type
    // Note done for alternative
    private static boolean isValidTypeString(String pv) {
        boolean rv = false;
        altqtype[] typearray = altqtype.values();
        for (altqtype aqt: typearray) {
            if (pv.equals(aqt.toString())) {
                rv = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public static qtype convertStringToQtype(String s) {
        qtype rv = qtype.TEXTENTRY; // <<<< Default
        if (isValidTypeString(s)) {
            rv = qtype.valueOf(s);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getOption1() {
        return option1;
    }

    public void setOption1(String option1) {
        this.option1 = option1;
    }

    public String getOption2() {
        return option2;
    }

    public void setOption2(String option2) {
        this.option2 = option2;
    }

    public String getOption3() {
        return option3;
    }

    public void setOption3(String option3) {
        this.option3 = option3;
    }

    public int getAnswerNumber() {
        return answerNumber;
    }

    public void setAnswerNumber(int answerNumber) {
        this.answerNumber = answerNumber;
    }

    public long getRowid() {
        return rowid;
    }

    public void setRowid(long rowid) {
        this.rowid = rowid;
    }
}
```

#### QuestionsTable.java :-

```
public class QuestionsTable {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "myquestions";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION1 = "option1";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION2 = "option2";
    public static final String COLUMN_OPTION3 = "option3";
    public static final String COLUMN_ANSWERNUMBER = "answernumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
}
```

#### DBHelper.java :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "questions.sqlite";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME +
                "(" +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWERNUMBER + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"  +
                //<<<< NOTE will default to "TEXTENTRY"
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '" +
                    Question.qtype.TEXTENTRY.toString() + "'" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void addQuestion(Question question){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1, question.getOption1());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2, question.getOption2());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3, question.getOption3());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWERNUMBER, question.getAnswerNumber());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE, String.valueOf(question.getMytype()));
        //<<<< alternative cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE,question.getMytype().toString());
        db.insert(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor getQuestionsAsCursor() {
        return db.query(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public ArrayList<Question> getQuestionsAsArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Question> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = db.query(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(new Question(
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWERNUMBER)),
                    //<<< get the String and convert to qtype
                    Question.convertStringToQtype(
                            csr.getString(
                                    csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE)
                            )
                    ),
                    csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ID))

            ));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prevquestion"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PREVIOUS"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextquestion"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NEXT"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/questionlist_by_cursor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="41">
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/questionlist_by_arraylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="41"
        android:background="#FFDDDDFF">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/questiondisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="14">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questiontext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerrb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/answercb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/answeret"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mQuestionText;
    Button mNext, mPrev;
    RadioButton mRadio;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
    EditText mTextEntry;
    ListView mQuestionListByCursor,mQuestionListByArrayList;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    ArrayList<Question> mQuestionArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<Question> mArrayAdapter;
    int mQuestionPointer = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mQuestionListByCursor = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.questionlist_by_cursor);
        mQuestionListByArrayList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.questionlist_by_arraylist);
        mNext = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nextquestion);
        mPrev = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.prevquestion);
        mRadio = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.answerrb);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.answercb);
        mTextEntry = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.answeret);
        mQuestionText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.questiontext);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        addSomeTestData(); //<<<< Add some test questions
        mQuestionArrayList = mDBHlpr.getQuestionsAsArrayList(); //<<<< get the questions
        refreshQuestion(); //<<<< Setup current (1st Question)


        //Via Cursor
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getQuestionsAsCursor();
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mCsr,
                new String[]{QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION,QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE},new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},0);
        mQuestionListByCursor.setAdapter(mSCA);

        //Via ArrayList
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mQuestionArrayList
        );
        mQuestionListByArrayList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
        mPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mQuestionPointer > 0) {
                    mQuestionPointer--;
                    refreshQuestion();
                }
            }
        });
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mQuestionPointer < (mQuestionArrayList.size() -1)) {
                    mQuestionPointer++;
                    refreshQuestion();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onDestroy()  {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!mCsr.isClosed()) {
            mCsr.close();
        }
    }

    private void addSomeTestData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(
                mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),
                QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME
        ) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.addQuestion(new Question(
                    "What is 1 + 1?",
                    "0","1","2",
                    2,
                    Question.qtype.CHECKBOX //<<<< uses shorter signature
            ));
            mDBHlpr.addQuestion(new Question(
                    "What is Tom's first name?",
                    "Fred","Tom","Bert",
                    1,
                    Question.qtype.TEXTENTRY //<<<< uses shorter signature
            ));
            mDBHlpr.addQuestion(new Question(
                    "Where is Timbuktu?",
                    "Afirca","Russia","Australia",
                    1,
                    Question.qtype.RADIO //<<<< uses shorter signature
            ));

        }
    }

    private void refreshQuestion() {
        Question q = mQuestionArrayList.get(mQuestionPointer);
        mQuestionText.setText(q.getQuestion());
        switch (q.getMytype()) {
            case TEXTENTRY:
                mTextEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case RADIO:
                mRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTextEntry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case CHECKBOX:
                mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTextEntry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Screen Shots :-

#### When first started or restart :-

[image]

Notes

- the List using a Cursor via `SimpleCursorAdapter` (1)
- the List using an `ArrayList<Question)` (2)

  - Note the `toString` method hasn't been overridden hence the default `toString` method resulting in the funny values displayed.
- the current (first) question, which as per the first list can be seen to be a checkbox question (3).

#### Next Question (question 2) after clicking the Next button :-

[image]

- EditText i.e. TEXTENTRY question

#### Next Question (question 3 now)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked as well:

In 
Question.java

```
enum QuestionType
{RADIO,CHECKBOX, TEXTENTRY}

public class Question {
    ...
    private QuestionType type;

    public Question(String question, String option1, String option2, String option3, int answerNumber,
                    QuestionType type) {
        ...
        this.type = type;
    }

    //generate getters and setters using the generate tool in Android Studio
        public QuestionType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(QuestionType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

then in 
QuizDnHelper.java

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;

    final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            ...
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT" + //not INTEGER!
            ")";

    ...

    private void fillQuestionsTable(){
    Question q1 = new Question("1 is correct", "a", "b","c",1,
            QuestionType.RADIO);


 private void addQuestion(Question question){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    ...
    //set and get enum as string:
    cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE, String.valueOf(question.getType()));
    ...
}

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            ...
            //set and get enum as string:
            question.setType(QuestionType.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_TYPE))));
            ...
        } while (c.moveToNext());
```

And to call this into MainActivity:

```
    QuestionType.RADIO
    ....
```

we use enums as a class.